# set numpy array to 0 without copy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am setting an existing array to zeros using the `numpy.zeros_like` function as follows:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(3, 3, 3, 3, 3)  # Some random data
x = np.zeros_like(x.shape)
```

I think the way I am doing it involves creating a new array of zeros and updating the reference to it. I was wondering if there is an efficient way to set everything to zeros without this initialization. The reason I need it is because it is called in an optimisation routine which gets called quite a few times.

Comment: [ndarray.fill](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html) (disclaimer: linked older docs; first google result; check your version of numpy)

Comment: @sascha Cannot believe I missed that...Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with `np.zeros([3,3,3,3,3])`

Comment: @percusse The filling with zeros does not necessarily only happen at initialization.

Comment: `zeros_like` takes an array, not its shape.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
x[:] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. That works as well. I am guessing this does not reallocate?

Comment: @Luca Just use  `x.fill(0)` it's almost 3 times faster than this python-level syntax.

Comment: @Kasramvd I ran some `%timeit`s and it performed 20% faster on (1000,1000) array, and margins of errors overlapped on a (1000,1000,1000) array. Even if there is a slight benefit, I guess you're very optimistic by saying _3 times faster_.